# Empty NFT when minting via Solidity Contract in Python ERC721

Tags: solidity

I have a problem when creating NFTs. I have created this contract and also used it correctly on the blockchain in my opinion. However, when I now want to mint NFTs via my Python application, they are empty. I can't see the image on either Opensea or Etherscan, but it was uploaded to IPFS and I can open it in my browser. I assume that I still have errors in the smart contract. I am working on Goerli Testnet at the moment.

I also find it interesting that I can see the following in the Transaction Details in the Logs section of the NFT under Data:

```
metaData :{"name": "My NFT", "description": "First NFT", "image": "ipfs://QmfPKFUu5DpEFCeCxa7TzR29QRonTKuScyBAsGphL15n4z"}
```

My contract is as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    uint256 private tokenCounter = 2;

    mapping(uint256 => string) public idToIPFSHash;

    event Mint(address indexed owner, uint256 indexed tokenId, string ipfsMetadata);

    constructor() ERC721("TheBiggerPictureNumeroUno", "TBPNU") {}

    function createNFTFromMetadata(string memory _ipfsMetadata) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 _tokenId = tokenCounter;
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId);
        idToIPFSHash[_tokenId] = _ipfsMetadata;
        emit Mint(msg.sender, _tokenId, _ipfsMetadata);
        tokenCounter++;
        return _tokenId;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "Invalid token ID");
        string memory ipfsMetadata = idToIPFSHash[tokenId];
        return ipfsMetadata;
    }

    function createNFTAndMetadata(string memory _ipfsMetadata) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 tokenId = createNFTFromMetadata(_ipfsMetadata);
        return tokenId;
    }
}
```

Comment: It takes times sometimes 
Can you attach a link to the mint transaction.

Comment: Yes of course: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x263fe772b4e1be050334faf71a542ead7e67ebcc25dea640eac4c7f4208b29ce

Comment: Can you share the Metadata link too?

Comment: I only have the image stored on IPFS and try to store the rest of the metadata directly on the blockchain.

Comment: And that is perhaps the mistake?

Comment: I made another change and now also load the metadata on IPFS. I can now see in the logs also the link to the metadata, but still an empty NFT at Opensea: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x7d8fa2b1dee317619c8b49bf1277fa051ecc4a971e831daeee5d2418cd2f58ad